# Add some text using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery, I have a div with H2 tags

```
<div id="preload"><h2></h2></div>
```

I would like to know how to use jQuery to add a text within the `<h2> tags`

Final result should be:

```
<div id="preload"><h2>Some text here</h2></div>
```

I need to add the text without replacing the tags `<h2></h2>` in the jQuery script.

Any ideas? Many thanks!

Comment: What's the larger picture?  There may be an easier way to do that

Comment: SomeKittens thanks for your comment...The larger picture was: I bought to had read in some place that it was possible to add text in an element without replacing the html tag already present ....so I wanted to have a confirmation if it really exist in this function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
$("div#preload h2").html("Some Text Here")
```

See the above code in action for your sample HTML **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/8u5TG/)**

Answer (score 9):

```
$("#preload h2").text('WOOt Woot');
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `.text`

```
$("#preload h2").text("Some text here");
```

Also not that this must be within either `$(document).ready(function () { ... })` or `$(function () { ... })`. I would use the latter as it saves typing.

```
$(function () {
    $("#preload h2").text("Some text here");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#preload h2').html('foo');
```

OR

```
$('#preload h2').text('foo');
```